# How can I properly add additional columns to the sales order grid?

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, grid

Is there a way (or several ways) to add additional columns to the sales order grid which one sees in the admin area?

Comment: I think the question might a bit too broad since depending on what additional column you want to display the solution would look different since one might require a join and another can take the information straight from the sales_order_grid table. It would also be good if you spelled out what properly means to you. To me it could mean anything between not hacking the core to no rewrites and making the new columns filterable.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it clean.

I'd observe `core_collection_abstract_load_before` and `adminhtml_block_html_before` events.

In the fist one I'd add `joinAttribute()`, `joinField()` and `join()` to the collection and in the second I'd `addColumn()` to the block.

Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: You'd consume all of the collection loads? Why not just observe `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just thinking further. Thinking about solution to modify any admin grid.

Answer (score 1):

You want to extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` in `app/code/local/Module/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order`, override the function `_prepareColumns()` and use `$this->addColumn`.  If you need to modify the collection to alter the SQL for the collection being used, override `_prepareCollection()` and call `Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())->getSelect()->joinLeft(...)`

> For both functions, return the result of
>   `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()` or
>   `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns()` rather than the
>   parent or your changes will get overwritten with the original behavior
>   from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom module that needs to add columns, this probably wont be for you, but for adding the payment method or something to the grid, this works fine:
https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids